# Bullet physics + QGLWidget (QT) for debug view

Tags: c++, qt, bulletphysics

I've just started to incorporate bullet in a QT application that I already have, in order to add physics simulations.

I have found samples that show how to use the dubugger of bullet in order to draw the physics world, but they are fairly simplistic, in the sense that they refer to very simplistic tools.

I can not find any example that blends bullet's debugger with QGLWidget for drawing.

Could somebody please provide some snippets or hints for this?
Is it do-able, or should one use a separate debugger with something simpler, like glut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something that does the job, so a fairly elementary example is running successfully.

Fore interested people, what helped me was [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945856/integrate-a-bullet-simple-demo-in-qt).

So, what I do, is that inside the `GLWidget::paintGL()` method I call the method `dynamicsWorld->debugDrawWorld()`, where `btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld;`.